# How to use async with Mutation in Django-graphene

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, graphene-django

I have a problem, where I want to optimise a client call to a mutation in a GraphQL API. The mutation executes 2 methods, where one is slow and where the result does not need to be send back to the client. I have tried to look at Django signals to handle this, but since signals are executed in sync, there is no benefit. Also, using Django signal request_finished seems not possible, because the method I need to execute needs to access model instance.

So my question is this.

Lets say I have a Django Model and I have two methods I use in a mutation.

```
class My_model(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField()

    def some_method():
       return "do something"
    
    def some_other_method():
       return "do something else"
```

Now I have a mutation like the one below, where I do not want the client to wait for the execution of the method `My_model.some_other_method()`

```
class CreateTwoObjects(graphene.Mutation):
     
     result = graphene.String()

     def mutate(self, info, input):
        
        result = My_model.some_method()
        # method to not wait for
        My_model.some_other_method()

        return CreateTwoObjects(result = result)
```

Is there a way I can execute this method in async and not have client wait for the return?

Comment: seems like graphene at this point is totally abandoned and you can see most questions regarding async, background tasks and performance overall get no answers.